# Is it still possible to use both vuetify and vue-bootstrap?

Tags: vue.js, vuetify.js

I have been using `vue-bootstrap` but I was thinking of switching to `vuetify`. However, I found out for some components, `vue-bootstrap` is much easier to integrate with backend.
So now I'm thinking of using both depending on the component. Does it still make sense to use both `vue-bootstrap` and `vuetify` on the same project? Or is there a problem if I use both frameworks?

Comment: There shouldn't be any problems using different components in different places. Components are supposed to be isolated after all.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Yes, it does not cause any issues to use both libraries in parallel. I tried it before within a medium size project without facing any problems.